# Formula anidada de Excel y su equivalencia en Python

Tags: python, excel

Soy nuevo aprendiendo python, disculpen lo básico que les puede parecer la pregunta, quisiera hacer en Python una instrucción equivalente a esta fórmula en excel (los nombres de las celdas en excel los cambié por las variables que ya tengo creadas en python)

SI(O((variable1>0),(Y(variable1=0,variable2>-1))),variable3,variable3-1)

No se como manejar la anidación de las funciones "o" e "y" en pyton, agradezco de antemano su apoyo.

Comment: Por lo que veo O y Y corresponden respectivamente a los operadores logicos or y and. Por ejemplo si tienes `O(condicion1, Y(condicion2, condicion3))`, eso sería equivalente a `condicion1 or (condicion2 and condicion3)`

Comment: Tal vez te sea útil la librería de pandas

Comment: @dante s. gracias, sí veo que son and y or las funciones equivalentes, lo que no sé es de qué forma puedo colocar toda la instrucción en python, considerando también los paréntesis, ya que un and forma parte de la función que contiene el or

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

En Excel el resultado de una fórmula se asigna a la celda en que aparece.

En python necesitarás asignar el resultado a alguna variable, digamos que lo asignas a una llamada `result`.

Tienes entonces dos formas de hacerlo:

1. Usando sentencias condicionales (es la forma más sencilla en mi opinión y la más frecuentemente utilizada)
2. Usando *expresiones* condicionales, que puede ser útil en caso de condiciones muy simples, pero que es en general más confusa y difícil de leer, aunque se puede parecer más a la expresión excel.

Veamos ambas soluciones:

### Usando una sentencia condicional

```
if (variable1 > 0 or (variable1 == 0 and variable2 > -1)):
  resultado = variable3
else:
  resultado = variable3 -1
```

### Usando una expresión condicional

```
resultado = variable3 if (variable1 > 0 or (variable1 == 0 and variable2 > -1)) else variable3-1
```

En ambos casos la expresión booeleana que decide qué asignar es la misma, y es la siguiente:

```
(variable1 > 0 or (variable1 == 0 and variable2 > -1))
```

Como ves, `Y()` equivale a poner todas las codiciones entre paréntesis separadas por `and`, mientras que `O()` equivale a ponerlas separadas por `or`. Los paréntesis son los que sirven para "anidar" unas en otras. Puedes omitir paréntesis en muchos casos sabiendo que `and` tiene "mayor precedencia" que `or`, es decir, que Python evaluará primero los `and` y después los `or`, pero creo que usar los paréntesis lo deja más claro aún cuando no son necesarios.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo @abulafia me sirvió tu explicación detallada, me ayudó bastante.